# Printing a receipt to a thermal printer MacOs .Net 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, escpos

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

I'm using [ESCPOS.NET library](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET) to print a check with a thermal printer.
The printer is connected to the Mac via usb.

It's requested the `portName` of the usb port, but I can't find it.
I used the `SerialPort.GetPortNames()`, but it was not displayed. There is other way to get the `portName`?

[Code](https://gist.github.com/TimurDavranov/dad762caa585a4b0fa3754bf105b963a)

Comment: Please, share the code so we can have more information.

Comment: It may be that the printer's hardware settings are not in serial port mode. If you have any tools, why don't you check them?

Comment: Printer model: Epson TM-T20II

Comment: Connected with usb cabel, this code i use https://gist.github.com/TimurDavranov/dad762caa585a4b0fa3754bf105b963a

Comment: Line 3, portName: "??????" my question.

Comment: `GetPortNames()` on MacOS is probably implemented here. [corefx/src/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialPort.OSX.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialPort.OSX.cs) If you can't call it and get `/dev/tty.??????` or `/dev/cu.??????`, then you probably have a lack of hardware mode settings or device driver installation.

Comment: In these /dev/tty.*** and /dev/cu.*** only have Bluetooth ports

Comment: It is better to isolate the situation. Can you print to that printer using other applications or test tools that do not use the ESC-POS-.NET library? If you can print from another program and the target device can be used in the ESC-POS-.NET library, use that device name. If the device name cannot be specified in the ESC-POS-.NET library or printing cannot be performed from other programs, review the printer settings and device driver installation.

Comment: I tried office, test print, etc. from other applications. Everything is fine with them. The fact is that when specifying a port I cannot find where to get this port, on the Internet it is written everywhere about this method with / dev /

Comment: It's probably because the hardware is set to printer class. Those prints will be done through the MacOS printer queue. Perhaps the ESC-POS-.NET library can't handle MacOS printer queues. You will be able to try changing the settings using the setting tool provided by EPSON on your Windows PC. Try removing the printer from MacOS, changing it to vendor class settings on your Windows PC, and then reconnecting to MacOS. [TM-T20II Software User's Manual - Epson](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/pos/bulk/tm-t20ii_swum_en_01.pdf)